# What's difference between "extends Test" and "extends Test[T]", are the exactly the same?

Tags: scala

I compile the following code, both of the last 2 lines are compiled succcessfully. But is there any difference bewteen them?

```
import scala.reflect.{classTag, ClassTag}
abstract class Test[T:ClassTag];
class Test_1[T:ClassTag] extends Test
class Test_1[T:ClassTag] extends Test[T]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty tricky.

[The spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html#context-bounds-and-view-bounds) says:

> A type parameter A of a method or non-trait class may also have one or
>   more context bounds A : T. In this case the type parameter may be
>   instantiated to any type S for which evidence exists at the
>   instantiation point that S satisfies the bound T. Such evidence
>   consists of an implicit value with type T[S].

In this case, the evidence is supplied by the context bound on the subclass.

So the compiler infers the same type arg as on the subclass.

You could check it like this.

Obviously, `res4` is not `Tag[Nothing]`. But that's just reporting the implicit evidence supplied to the superclass constructor, which is the implicit `Tag[T]` from `Test_1`.

```
scala> abstract class Test[T:ClassTag] { def f = implicitly[ClassTag[T]] }
defined class Test

scala> class Test_1[T:ClassTag] extends Test { def g = implicitly[ClassTag[T]] } 
defined class Test_1

scala> new Test_1().f
res2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = Nothing

scala> new Test_1().g
res3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = Nothing

scala> new Test_1[Thread]().f
res4: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Thread] = java.lang.Thread

scala> new Test_1[Thread]().g
res5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Thread] = java.lang.Thread
```

Nothing amazing, just showing that making `Nothing` explicit changes the result at `res8`.

```
scala> class Test2[T:ClassTag] extends Test[Nothing] { def g = implicitly[ClassTag[T]] }
defined class Test2

scala> new Test2().f
res6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = Nothing

scala> new Test2().g
res7: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = Nothing

scala> new Test2[Thread]().f
res8: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = Nothing

scala> new Test2[Thread]().g
res9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Thread] = java.lang.Thread
```

And it doesn't work with two type parameters:

```
scala> abstract class Test[T:TypeTag, U: TypeTag] { def f = (implicitly[TypeTag[T]],implicitly[TypeTag[U]]) }
defined class Test

scala> class Test1[X: TypeTag, Y: TypeTag] extends Test { def g = implicitly[TypeTag[X]] }
<console>:11: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value evidence$2 of type reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Y]
 and value evidence$1 of type reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[X]
 match expected type reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]
       class Test1[X: TypeTag, Y: TypeTag] extends Test { def g = implicitly[TypeTag[X]] }
                                                   ^
```

Another view:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> abstract class Top[A: TypeTag] { def f = implicitly[TypeTag[A]] }
defined class Top

scala> class Bot[B: TypeTag] extends Top { def g = implicitly[TypeTag[B]] }
defined class Bot

scala> new Bot[String]().f
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String] = TypeTag[String]

scala> new Bot[String]().g
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String] = TypeTag[String]

scala> class Not[B: TypeTag] extends Top[Nothing] { def g = implicitly[TypeTag[B]] }
defined class Not

scala> new Not[String]().f
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Nothing] = TypeTag[Nothing]

scala> new Not[String]().g
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String] = TypeTag[String]
```

Or, showing the type inference more simply:

```
scala> class Knot[A: TypeTag] { def f = implicitly[TypeTag[A]] }
defined class Knot

scala> def f = { implicit val x = typeTag[Top[String]] ; val k = new Knot ; k.f }
f: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Top[String]]
```